# Why can't we create static array with custom keys in javascript in one single line like PHP

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to declare an static array in Javascript:

```
let arr = ['a':'a1','b':'b2','c':'c3'] //gives error
```

Trying to declare an static array in PHP:

```
$arr = ['a'=>'a1','b'=>'b2','c'=>'c3'] //works
```

Objects can be made using {} why not array with [] having custom keys?

I am not compating Js and PHP but just a big WHY ? Why only Objects not Array ?

Comment: What is your requirement? Can you try to use Objects instead of array for dynamic keys?

Comment: Just because something works in PHP doesn't make it valid syntax in JS. You need an object and not an array.

Comment: Why Object. I want to use Array. Half of the functions are working on Array instead of Object. Than why cant we make array in this manner. If no then why PHP allows this and js dosnt ?

Comment: Because they are completely different languages

Comment: But why ? is there any problem ? Why not allowed ? Why only Object ? Why not Array ?

Comment: Why? Because... You cannot expect to completely different things to work exactly the same way o.O

Comment: Many things done in Array are similarly working in Objects too! Than why partiality during declaration ? There might be some depth to dive for this !

Comment: JS' understanding of an Array is an *(ordered)* list of values. and its understanding of an Object is an *(unordered)* collection of key-value pairs. That's the main distinction, that's what the literals are supposed to build. But now comes technicality, since JS' Array inherit from Object you can add arbitrary properties to them, like to any other Object *(including Functions)* **just not through the literal!**

Comment: My question would be why do you need these keys on arrays? What benefit do you think you'll get from that? In your perception, what does an array provide that an object does not?

Comment: @Thomas I wanted to use array function ! Can I run that on Objects? Array Splice. Can i use that on object ? There should be this easy way to declare array.

Comment: You can [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) properties from an object. Or you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) them: `const {a, ...rest} = {'a':'a1','b':'b2','c':'c3'};` a bit like PHPs [list()](https://www.php.net/list) function. And `rest` would be a new object containing all the other properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the built-in Array type in JavaScript, I believe this is as close as you can get, using `Object.assign` to clone named properties from an object to an Array object. But it's very doubtful if this will actually do what you think it will do.

```
const a = Object.assign([1,2,3], {a:4, b:5, c:6});
```

You can do this because an array IS an object, just of a special type, with special `Array.prototype` functions for dealing with its numerically keyed members.

But if you were thinking you would be able to use things like `.map` or `.forEach` to loop through (non-numerically) named properties, it won't work. Those are special cases that only work with numerically keyed array items. Try doing this with the above array:

```
a.forEach(x=> console.log(x));
// output:
// => 1
// => 2
// => 3
```

the `a/b/c` properties don't show up.

A better solution, and more likely to do what you actually want, would be to make your own custom "class," something like this:

```js
function NamedArray(init) {
  Object.assign(this, init);
}
NamedArray.prototype.forEach = function(callback) {
  const keys = Object.entries(this);
  keys.forEach(([key, value],array)=> callback(value, key, array));
}

const arr = new NamedArray({a:1,b:2,c:3});
arr.forEach((value,key)=> {
  console.log(key, value);
})
```

You can create all the class methods that you need, using this pattern.

Note: There is also [ES6 syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) for creating these classes, which can make creating objects with lots of prototype methods and properties much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not using {}, but []. [] are arrays - not objects. {} are objects - very json-like, but can contain everything - from numbers to functions